# C++ using getline() prints: pointer being freed was not allocated in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, malloc, getline

I'm trying to use std:getline() but getting a strange runtime error:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x10000a720: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

This is the code that produces this error:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
   std::istringstream my_str("demo string with spaces");
   std::string word;

   while (std::getline(my_str, word, ' ')) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Before each word I get this error. From the comments it seems to be a OSX/XCode specific error. Any hints on that?

**Update:**
The error is only printed in Debug mode. If I build this code in Release mode everything is fine.

**Update 2:**
More info on that issue can be found [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg01199.html).

**Solution:**

Set

> _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1

in your Preprocessor Macros in targets info build tab.

System info:

> OSX 10.6.2 | XCode 3.2 | g++ 4.2 | debug config for i386

Comment: It runs fine on my machine.  I'm not using a MacBook though so that might have something to do with it maybe but on XP with VS2008 it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Likewise, it compiles and runs without errors on my PPC Powerbook. Mac OS 10.4 with g++ 4.0.1. And it looks right...

Comment: Compiles and runs fine under Visual Studio 2008 for me too.

Comment: Works fine for me on my MacBook Pro with 10.5.8 g++ 4.0.1 and valgrind doesn't report anything suspicious either.

Comment: Works fine for me, MacBook Pro, 10.6.2 and g++ 4.2.1. Where does malloc_error_break get called?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: right before it prints the word.

Comment: @dan: Looks like your setup may be wonky somehow. Try it with terminal `g++` in a fresh terminal, then consider a reboot, then consider a reinstallation of the developer tools.

Comment: `getline => string::append => string::reserve => free`: I can reproduce it only within XCode, not from the command line.

Comment: To reproduce with Xcode, make sure to include `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` on the g++ command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least one person has reported problems with g++ 4.2.1 on Apple that seem possibly related to yours having to do with an improper configuration of the standard library with the `_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING` definition (not that I understand any of what I'm typing here).

You might get a bit of a clue from the newsgroup thread that includes this message:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2009-10/msg00807.html

Comment: This is it. I reproduced the problem and fixed it by adding `_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING` to the target settings window. (Do not add it to the "Preprocessing" section of the *Project* settings window; that does nothing. XCode, grrrrr…)

Comment: Since this is a team effort, would someone like to report a bug?