# using string to read file - Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

The following does not work and gives me a SIGABRT when I run in the debugger:

---

```
std::ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("/Users/fernandonewyork/inputText.txt");    

cout << inFile << endl;

vector<string> inText;

if (inFile) {
    string s4;

    while (inFile>>s4) {
        inText.push_back(s4);
    }

}
inFile.close();
```

---

The following does:

---

```
std::ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("/Users/fernandonewyork/inputText.txt");    

cout << inFile << endl;

vector<string> inText;

if (inFile) {
    string s4("This is no lnger an empty string");

    while (inFile>>s4) {
        inText.push_back(s4);
    }

}
inFile.close();
```

---

I was under the impression I was able to simply use s4 without having to worry about any space considerations, or is something else happening here?  This is the full error I get from the top code:

malloc: *** error for object 0x100010a20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Comment: Have you tried seting s4 to null to allocate the space?

Comment: Is this all the code? The problem doesn't seem to be happening here, this part looks okay. Also, you don't need to initialise `s4`.

Answer (score 1):

This egregious bug was covered by [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234557/c-using-getline-prints-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-in-xcode):

> Solution:
>
> Set
>
> ```
> _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1
> ```
>
> in your Preprocessor Macros in targets
>   info build tab.

There is another settings window with a Preprocessor Macros field (project settings?) but setting this there will have no effect.

— Hmm, that issue is rather different from this one, but ironically your symptom is more common.

Comment: Applying the above setting (_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1) resolved the issue.  Both versions of the code now work.